# Programatically create native DLL using VsDevCmd.bat

Tags: winapi

I need to run `VsDevCmd.bat` with parameters but, when I run this code,  `VsDevCmd.bat` gets executed but no parameters get passed in.

The code is following :

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShExecInfo = {0};
ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
ShExecInfo.fMask = NULL;
ShExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpVerb = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpFile = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat";
ShExecInfo.lpParameters = "cl.exe /D_USRDLL /D_WINDLL C:\\MyDLL.cpp C:\\MyDLL.def /link /DLL /OUT:MyDLL.dll";
ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = "C:\\";
ShExecInfo.nShow = SW_MAXIMIZE;
ShExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL;

int nRet = (int) ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfo);

if (nRet >= 32)
{
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();
    char szMsg[250];
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, 0, dw, 0, szMsg, sizeof(szMsg), NULL);
    MessageBox(hWnd, szMsg, "ERROR", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
}

WaitForSingleObject (ShExecInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
```

Comment: The question has nothing to do with C++ why you added c++ tag then?

Comment: I think `VsDevCmd.bat` does not support any parameters.

Comment: This code has many mistakes and misconceptions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compile a DLL from within your application and you're using Visual Studio why don't you execute devenv to build a solution file containing the DLL you want to build?

Have a look at the documentation of [devenv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b20w810z.aspx).

So your code should look like this:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShExecInfo = {0};
ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
ShExecInfo.fMask = NULL;
ShExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpVerb = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpFile = "devenv";
ShExecInfo.lpParameters = "/build yoursolution.sln";
ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = "C:\\";
ShExecInfo.nShow = SW_MAXIMIZE;
ShExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL;

if (ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfo) != FALSE)
{
    WaitForSingleObject (ShExecInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);

    DWORD exitCode;        
    if (GetExitCodeProcess(ShExecInfo.hProcess, &exitCode) != FALSE)
    {
        /*
        **  Process exit code of devenv 
        **  I haven't found something on the internet but I assume that exitCode=0 means success!
        */
        if (exitCode != 0)
        {
            MessageBox(hWnd, "devenv failed!", "ERROR", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        DWORD dw = GetLastError();
        char szMsg[250];
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, 0, dw, 0, szMsg, sizeof(szMsg), NULL);
        MessageBox(hWnd, szMsg, "ERROR", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);        
    }

    CloseHandle(ShExecInfo.hProcess);
}
else
{
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();
    char szMsg[250];
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, 0, dw, 0, szMsg, sizeof(szMsg), NULL);
    MessageBox(hWnd, szMsg, "ERROR", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
}
```

Comment: Hi Lukas, thank you very much for solution ! My problem is, that I need to install my program and then from within the program compile a DLL using a compiler. I would prefer the VS Toolkit but If you have a solution for different compiler like GCC let me to know please ?

Comment: @A.Williams: If you prefer another toolchain you can use a makefile and simply spawn a make process processing that makefile. Using this you can use any toolchain you like... There are numerous examples on the internet. Another point: I don't know what your program is doing but compiling a DLL at the machine of the user does not seem wise to me (and you create dependencies to required tools (compiler, linker, ...) which may not be available (or in different locations) on another machine).